# Solving combination problem with inclusion-exclusion principle

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, inclusion-exclusion

Problem: In the word 'combination' How many arrangements have no two adjacent letters the same?

My solution:

Using the inclusion-exclusion principle as follows:

$|A_1 \cup B_1 \cup A_3| = |A_1| + |A_2| + |A_3| - |A_1 \cap A_2|- |A_1 \cap A_3| - |A_2 \cap A_3| + |A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3|$

$|A_1|=|A_2|=|A_3|= \frac{10!}{2!2!}$

$|A_1 \cap A_2|=|A_1 \cap A_3|=|A_2 \cap A_3| = \frac{9!}{2!}$

$|A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3| = 8!$

So to find the total arrangements where no two letters are adjacent I subtracted all the cases of adjacent letters from the total of arrangements with no restrictions, so I have:

$\frac{11!}{2!2!2!} - 3\times\frac{10!}{2!2!} - 3 \times \frac{9!}{2!} + 8!$

However I am aware this is wrong and I am supposed to add the $3 \times \frac{9!}{2!}$ instead, can't seem to wrap my head around why this is because why would we want to add instance where two adjacent letters occur?

Edit: I have found my issue thanks to the responses, I simply forgot that the sign flips to a + because of the two minuses, a mistake to remember for next time!

Comment: $|X| - |A\cup B\cup C| = |X| - \left(|A|+|B|+|C|-|A\cap B|-|A\cap C|-|B\cap C|+|A\cap B\cap C|\right)$.  Here notice that the subtraction away from $|X|$ affects *everything* in the parentheses and that when you subtract a negative that is the same as adding a positive.  If your question is why in inclusion-exclusion we alternate signs... you need to learn the proof for inclusion-exclusion in the first place.

Comment: The punchline is that with $|A\cup B|$ if we were to compare that to $|A|+|B|$ then this second might have been *too much*.  Those elements who were in both $A$ and $B$ would have contributed to the sum more than once and so to correct the count we subtract it away, giving $|A\cup B|=|A|+|B|-|A\cap B|$.  The fully general inclusion-exclusion principle follows from the two-set version and induction.